# How do I get a distinctive IP Address?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I see Google has `8.8.8.8` and CloudFlare has `1.1.1.1`. How do I get myself a distinctive IP address? What's involved in acquiring something that has a pattern in it?

Comment: maybe safe your energy before betting on a dying horse IPv4 ... and go for IPv6 where many addresses are still available

Comment: IPv4 has been dying for like what, 20 years by now?

Comment: The IPv4 experiment was supposed be properly re-engineered 40 years ago. It escaped to production and has been legacy ever since.   https://youtu.be/-Uwjt32NvVA

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Roughly this:

1. Become a LIR ([Local Internet Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_Internet_registry#Local_Internet_registry))
2. Obtain and set up your AS ([Autonomous System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)))
3. Decide what address you'd like to use (e.g. 7.7.7.7)
4. Find out who currently has it assigned: `whois 7.7.7.7`. Ok, it's US army, try a different one: [`whois 77.77.77.77`](https://apps.db.ripe.net/db-web-ui/query?searchtext=77.77.77.77) - cool someone from Iran.
5. Contact them and *offer them loads of money* for transferring the `77.77.77.0/24` allocation to you.
6. Propagate it from your AS and enjoy!

Alternative way: use your loads of money to buy the entire company that owns the block you like.

Comment: Actually, the longest IPv4 mask that other ISPs will accept as an advertisement from you is `/24`. You will need to acquire the `/24` or shorter prefix from the current holder, and you will need the consent of your RIR for that, too.

Comment: You probably don't need to become a LIR, and you could get someone else to advertise for you, so you probably don't need to get an AS. There are also rules about PI/PA adverting that may prevent some sub-blocks to be transferred (no idea how/if this is enforced nowadays, it's been a looooong time since I dealt with that).

Comment: I could definitely see Google buying a company primarily for a cool IP address.  Are there any recorded examples of this happening?

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 could probably be simplified by providing somewhat reasonable amounts of money to an entity that is already a LIR with an AS. However, it would be best to choose that entity so it depends on the same RIR as the IP you want.

Comment: frankly though, I suspect most companies who could reasonablly consider getting vanity IPs are probablly LIRs already.

Comment: and ultimately step 5,. spend a lot of money is the key detail.  As long as you have money to burn everything else can be managed; if you don't have a pile of money it's not going to happen under any circumstances.

Comment: Although for someone subject to US law, like OP, giving loads of money to 'someone' in Iran might well be a sanctions violation and land you in prison. Where, TTBOMK but not IME, you usually aren't permitted _any_ Internet access.